# Predefine a set of Keywords in CSS to add attributes to

Tags: css, html, keyword, pseudo-class

I'm looking for css code that will change the color of repeating keywords. I know ican use a pseudo class and the `<i>` tag to make the changes but i'm looking for css code to remove the need to use the `<i>`. Basicallly can i predefine a set of keywords?

```
.div i {color:purple}

<div>  
    <p>this would be fine <i> if </i> this was the only need for the <i>.
       but with <i> multiple uses </i> over and over again, brings the need for a 
        <i> short cut</i>.
        </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Aren't you in control of setting the <i> and can control the nesting on that way? Btw: Don't see any pseudo class here... Pseudo classes start with : like :hover.

Comment: _“Basicallly can i predefine a set of keywords?”_ – no, you can’t. And CSS can format the content of _elements_ only (with a few exceptions), so without an encapsulating element no separate formating of any text.

Comment: From comments you can see this is not and available feature.  You really should consider using the more generic `<span>` element for this rather than `<i>` which typically has its own connotation.

Comment: Have you considered using javascript?